# I get notification for TB Sirate Starter update despite that I use new fresh drupal installation

Tags: updating, notifications

I get notification for TB Sirate Starter update despite that I use new fresh drupal installation, never setup TB Sirate Starter. This repeated many times and on many of my new drupal project.

I only tested it in the past on my local server. But I always setup fresh and clean drupal installation.

Is there any soultion

Comment: Of course it is bad. And it will get worse, because [TB Sirate Starter](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_sirate_starter) is obsolete. Why use an unsupported feature?

Answer (score 1):

Despite not using the distribution any more I keep getting the message to update TB Sirate Starter

====================================

I had this issue before and yes, I took notes.
In my case it was solved by finding the culprit(s). They were **jquery_plugin** and **jquery_update**

```
# grep -r "tb_sirate_starter" .
./sites/all/modules/jquery_plugin/jquery_plugin.info:project = "tb_sirate_starter"
./sites/all/modules/jquery_update/jquery_update.info:project = "tb_sirate_starter"
```

The fix / workaround?

I deleted the directories jquery_plugin/ and jquery_update/

Then reinstalled them.

```
# grep -r "tb_sirate_starter" .
#
```

No more messages "Update Available - TB Sirate Starter "
And I think this is what the OP asked :)